# How do I do a simple onClick to change a child component's classname with React Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have React Redux working to change my child component's classname, but I do it via

```
//Subscribe with our function that sets our state
this.props.store.subscribe( this.onSelectChange );
```

(where the `onSelectChange` is a function in my component that changes a property on its state.

According to the redux docs, I should instead be using "a view binding library" like ReactRedux's connect method. But every tutorial is incredibly complex. They're hard to understand and appear to be about 5 times more code than what I need to use right now. Using Redux directly, I have about 6 lines of total code.

How can i *simply* use the "proper" way to make my child component change its classname?

Answer (score 2):

If really all you need is to update a classname on click, React is perfectly capable of doing this without involving the Redux store.

The whole idea with React is that each component has some `state` object, and a `render` function to turn the state into markup. If you want to change your view, you should change the `state` and let React call `render` again. Take the following example which toggles the classname of a button (not tested):

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      highlighted: false
    }
    this.buttonClicked = this.buttonClicked.bind(this);
  }

  buttonClicked() {
    var highlighted = !this.state.highlighted
    this.setState({
      highlighted: highlighted
    })
  }

  render(){
    var classname = this.state.highlighted ? "highlighted-btn" : "normal-btn"
    return (
      <button onClick={this.buttonClicked} className={classname} />
    )
  }
}
```

We trigger `render` by calling `setState`, in which we use the state to determine the classname for the button.

Comment: I'm trying to use it to learn Redux and I need it to also update other siblings to no longer be selected.

Comment: @DonRhummy Redux shouldn't be used to maintain view state (i.e which buttons are selected). That should almost certainly be component state. A simple on click and toggling selected states isn't really a use case for Redux so I'm afraid it's not really going to help you learn it properly.

Comment: According to the creator of redux, that's wrong: https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-generating-containers-with-connect-from-react-redux-addtodo

Comment: @DonRhummy The example in the video is more complicated than what you're asking for in your question. He has actual data to manipulate (Todos), while you just want to change a classname, which is a view level concern, not a data layer concern. I've showed you how to implement a simple classname change on click which is what you asked for. I would never involve redux for something so simple.

Comment: "which is what you asked for." no it's not. I asked how to do with React Redux

Comment: @DonRhummy In the question you asked for the simple and "proper" way to update a child component's classname, which I've shown you. Maybe I'm confused though, I'm wondering why you are hooking up `this.onSelectChange` to the Redux store  instead of simple attaching it to your clickable element directly with `onClick={this.onSelectChange}`. Any reason for that?

Comment: It's because there was a selected item and each item needs to change (either to true/false) based on that. So if item #1 gets clicked, it needs to tell all its siblings to unselect themselves

Answer (score 0):

#### solution 1

well, if you change className because you want different style.

I will suggest you can use `setState` in its childComponent instead.

[here is for your reference](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-3-identify-the-minimal-but-complete-representation-of-ui-state)

#### solution 2

on the other hand, if you want to use Redux to achieve that.

you probably need to have a reducer first. let's say `selectState`

and then you need an action. here we name it `changeSelectState`

now, we can use `connect` from `react-redux` on the `container component`

and pass this method down to that `presentational component`. that's it.

So, the flow you can do is

1. add a reducer for storing data
2. add an action for changing the data
3. import that data and action via `connect` into `container component`
4. pass them down to `presentational component`
5. click and change the value via that action

Comment: I need it to also update other siblings to no longer be selected.